# How to get hingeJoint2D anchor point in unity 2d?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to Instantiate a particle system at the same location of a hinge joint.

Here is my current code:

```
void OnJointBreak2D(Joint2D brokenJoint){ 
    Instantiate(blood_particles, brokenJoint.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
}
```

This instantiates the particle at the location of the gameobject that the joint was attached to.

Comment: I'm confused now .. at which position do you want to spawn? I think a graphic might help to understand what exact point your are looking for

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.